# Znc bouncer connection log

Tags: logging, irc

I'm trying to find connection logs to my znc server. I've reset my password and i am having trouble connecting to the server, but i cannot find the logs of the connection anywhere. I tried

> systemctl status znc

and it gives me nothing, just info about znc starting.

Does anyone know if this kind of logging is supported? And if so how to activate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `znc --debug` to get full output.

Comment: Thanks! i had to manually run znc as the user znc and see the output in the terminal, but that helped a lot of the debugging, but how do i activate logging in a file for znc?

Comment: `znc --debug > log.txt` or if the service is ran by `systemd` it will be picked up by `journald` anyway?

Comment: Yes, actually that worked. I had to modify the .service file to add the debug. The log is indeed picked up by journald.